# Add a list to a list

Tags: android, list, button, adapter

I have a ArrayList Buttons and a ArrayList newButtons. Is there any possibility to add the newButtons list "behind" the Buttons List?
I tried with an Adapter but I failed.

```
ArrayAdapter<Button> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Button>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Buttons);
```

I don't know if that's the right way for an Adapter.

```
for (int a = 0; a < newButtons.size(); a++){
        adapter.add(newButtons.get(a));
    }
```

This is what I tried to add the newButtons list.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists both store the same type you can achieve this by calling `buttons.addAll(newButtons);`

Comment: Okay thank you that works nice but now he always says: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.ArrayAdapter#addAll and i changed it in manifest. But the error disappears when i clean the project, but when I save it then the error comes back.

Comment: @Lars3n95 have you managed to solve this? I have no idea about the problem. Maybe you should start another question about this.